# In python, which binary operators can have both operands of NoneType?

Tags: python

The code is a list comprehension but the list itself is not required.
I'm only using the list comprehension to code-golf.
I want both calls, `func1` and `func2`, to execute. Their return type is `NoneType`. I have used the `or` operator which worked for me.
I can't use `and` because it will short-circuit after the first call since `NoneType` is false-y. I can't use `+` as it throws an error.
I found I can also use `==`. What other operands can take their place?

In other words, I want a binary operator that doesn't throw an error when both operands are NoneType and will always evaluate both operands before returning/will never short-circuit? The return value is irrelevant to me.

Input:

```
3 0
1 4
5 0
8 7
```

Code:

```py
[ func1(x, y) or func2(y, x) for _ in range(4) for x, y in [map(int, input().split())] ]
```

This also works for me: (using ==)

```py
[ func1(x, y) == func2(y, x) for _ in range(4) for x, y in [map(int, input().split())] ]
```

I sure would love to hear any other tips on code-golfing this further.

Comment: what about just making a tuple? `(func1(x, y), func2(y, x), )` ?

Comment: have you tried `[ (func1(x, y) is None and func2(y, x) is None) for _ in range(4) for x, y in [map(int, input().split())] ]` ?